# Is there any library, plugin for Visual Studio 2012, or any other tool or way to create C# initializer class for existing database?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, entity-framework

Using SQL Server Management Studio we have ability to script entire existing database to one sql script with all database schema and data. What I need is some tool, which will automatically create similar C# database initializer class or classes, which will represent database structure model, and fill this database with it's data. Maybe is it possible somehow to convert SQL script to C#? Any suggestions?

P.S. To create database I use EntityFramework codefirst strategy.

Comment: You want C# code to create the database and fill it with data? If you already have a SQL script that does this, can you just run that script from your C# code?

Comment: Why would you do something so horrible.  Just supple the sql script file and use that to fill your database.